# Transform Json array without key to SOQL format in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

Transform Json format as below

**Input:**

```
["100555809","100000001"]
```

into the following format so that it can be used in the SOQL query by assigning the transformed output some flow variable in salesforce connector.

**Output:**

```
('100555809','100000001')
```

Comment: @Moderators, in case this is irrelevant question, please let me know the solution and then I can bring this post down(delete it).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish? There might be better ways to do this than creating a string that represents a SOQL array.

Comment: I want to achieve the output via dataweave in Mule. For now I am using a expression component. So just wanted to know if there is any better way to do it. I have edited the post with expression component that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is the payload and you want a string as output, you'll want to use `map` to wrap all your IDs in single quotes, then `joinBy` to join them into a single string. Finally, you'll wrap the result in parenthesis:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

%var ids = payload

// Wrap ids in single quotes and join them into a string
%function formatIds(ids)
  ids 
    map ((id) -> "'$(id)'")
    joinBy ","

%function transformForSOQL(ids)
  "($(formatIds(ids)))"
---
transformForSOQL(ids)
```

Not sure if SOQL is exposed to the same vulnerabilities, but if it is, be careful of "SOQL" injection when generating dynamic query values like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help @jerney

Comment: No problem. If this answer worked for you please accept it! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers